# Update data value in Elm

Tags: elm

I am trying to change object data value before reusing it.

I have a data type

```
type alias Definition =
    { title : String
    , description : String
    , image : String

    }
```

-- using original data coming from API

```
    getDescription : Tag -> (Definition -> a) -> String -> Maybe Definition -> Html a
    getDescription tag msg name def =
            case def of
                Just d ->
                        div [] [
                            div [] [ text d.title ]
                            , div [] [ text d.description ]

-- trying to change description with removeDescription function      
                            , div [] [ newDescription (removeDescription d) ] 

                            ]
                Nothing ->
                    div [] [ text "name"]





newDescription : Definition -> Html a
newDescription d =
    div [] [ 
        div[] [d.title] 
        , div[] [ d.description ]        -- trying to use new description
        ]
```

-- This function fails

```
removeDescription : Definition -> Definition
removeDescription d = 
        { d | d.description = '' }   -- This fails
```

I have tried

String.replace

but it still fails

Is it even possible to change data like this way considering Elm make sure data immutability ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be more certain if you also posted Elm's (helpful!) error message, but it seems like in your example you want `description` instead of `d.description` when you update the record (which is syntactic sugar for returning a new record with other values unchanged -- as you note, Elm features purity / data immutability).

Example in the Elm REPL using your record type:

```
> d = Definition "Test" "Hello World" "0000"
{ description = "Hello World", image = "0000", title = "Test" }
    : Definition
> d2 = {d | description = ""}
{ description = "", image = "0000", title = "Test" }
    : { description : String, image : String, title : String }
```

There are some more examples from the [Elm docs](https://elm-lang.org/docs/records)

Comment: I was doing {d | d.description = " " } instead . Thanks